# WPF Button: IsMouseOver trigger not working

Tags: wpf

**Expected Behavior:**

I want to display a button with greenish linear-gradient as background and white foreground.
The button should change color on mouse hover- yellow background and black foreground.

**Actual/Erratic Behavior:**

The button's foreground changes to black on mouse-over but background doesn't.

**Code**

```xml
<Button x:Name="saveButton" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="317,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"  Click="Button_Click_1">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" value="Black"/>                       
            </Trigger>                            
         </Style.Triggers>
         <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
               <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF64E24C" Offset="1"/>
               </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I tried various solution on Google & Stack Overflow like using ControlTemplate but none of them worked.

Comment: It's because default template for `Button` uses `ColorAnimation` on hover to change background

Comment: I tried to use my own template but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you show your template?

Comment: Sorry..I deleted it. But why doesn't this code work. I mean shouldn't this specific trigger override the default one.

Comment: No. Animation has higher priority then style trigger. Check [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing)

Comment: In the above mentioned link, there is an example given by MSDN.According to it, my trigger should work. The MSDN example also uses default template for Button but there it is mentioned that the trigger will work & background will turn blue on mouse over.

Comment: Not with a default template. Copy the example, into new project, and you'll see blue for a brief moment until animation from default template kick in. Animations have higher priority

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67574/discussion-between-abhilash-and-dkozl).

Comment: I copied your code. Fixed two typoes ("value" and "true" both should be in capital letters) and it works as expected. Chances are there is some other style that interferes with the button style.